# Convert string to date format in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, date

'20180227' how i can convert this to date format in python

Tried with this , let suppose we similar string in entire columns of pandas data frame.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['colaname'])
```

But showing me 1970 date which is default . Any solution on this please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `format` for `YYYYMMDD` - `%Y%m%d`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['colaname'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

If possible some values not match this format and need convert them to `NaT`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['colaname'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```